# Probability of two people sitting next to each other in 2 rows

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There's a table like this:

[image]

Each square represents a chair.

> 10 people are attending a meeting, among them Mr. Smith and Mrs. Sykes. The attendees will be sitting at the table in the picture.
>   What is the probability of Mr. Smith and Mrs. Sykes sitting next to
>   each other?

I did:

- total combinations: $$10!$$
- probability of them sitting on the same side of the table: $$2*(\frac{10*4}{10*9}) = 2 * \frac{40}{90} = \frac{80}{90} = \frac{8}{9}$$
- probability of them sitting next to each other, given that they are sitting at the same side of the table: $$\frac{^5C_2}{5*4}*\frac{8}{9}=\frac{4}{9}$$
- final probability:
  $$\frac{\frac{4}{9}}{10!}$$

However, my book says the solution is $\frac{37}{45}$.

What did I do wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll write my solution.

Let's count how many ways to sit Smith and Sykes together there are. We can put them in $16$ ways (choose the two chairs and then the order). No matter where they sit down, there are $8!$ ways to put the other people.

The probability is
$$\frac{8!\cdot16}{10!}=\frac8{45}$$

However, the probability that they are **not** next to each other is
$$1-\frac8{45}=\frac{37}{45}$$

Your solution is wrong, but did you misread the book, too?

Answer (score 1):

First, why did you multiply by $2$ for the chance they are on the same side?  After the first sits, the second can sit in four chairs on the same side and five on the other, so the chance is $\frac 49$.    If they are on the same side, you have $\frac 25$ chance the first to sit is on the end, then $\frac 14$ that the other sits next by, and $\frac 35$ chance that the first does not sit on the end and $\frac 12$ chance the other sits next by, so the chance they are next to each other is $\frac 25 \cdot \frac14 + \frac 35 \cdot \frac 12=\frac 25$.Overall, this gives $\frac 49 \cdot \frac 25 \cdot =\frac 8{45}$. If you are going to count arrangements, as your $10!$ indicates, you should count arrangements instead of probabilities.  Then there are four ways to seat the first in a corner, one way to seat the second next by, and $8!$ ways to seat the rest, plust six ways to seat the first not in a corner, two ways to seat the second next by, and $8!$ ways to seat the rest, for $\frac {16\cdot 8!}{10!}=\frac 8{45}$ again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what I wasn't doing properly (other than misreading the question).

What was confusing me was that I was trying to calculate all sets where Smith and Sykes sit together and then I was dividing that by the *total possible ways to arrange the table.* Basically, I was trying to find the probabilty of sets of 2 in a group of sets of 10...

So, a simpler way of solving this would be:

There are 8 possible ways of Smith and Sykes sitting together on *one* side of the table. Because the table has two sides, multiplying that by 2 equals 16 sets.

The total amount of sets of 2 is 10*9, so if I do $\frac{16}{10*9}$ I get $\frac{8}{45}$.

To get the probability of them not sitting together, I have to do $$1-\frac{8}{45} = \frac{37}{45}$$

@RossMillikan @ajotatxe I can understand your answers, but here I point out the cause of my confusion. Your answers were important to make me understand how to solve this, but I am going to vote this as the main answer for future reference, in case I make the same mistake again.

Thanks for your help